# Can anyone fully explain the six constant mitzvos?

Tags: mitzvah

I know what the six constant mitzvos are, but can anyone give a detailed explanation of them?
(Preferably sourced.)

Comment: What do want to know?  Whole books have been written about them, such as: 
     https://www.artscroll.com/Products/SIXH.html

Comment: Rabbi Ari Bensoussan has a great series of classes on them. Here's the first: https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?v=30675

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of detailed explanations available online, e.g.,

- [R Noach Weinberg from aish](https://www.aish.com/jl/m/cm/)
- [R Jack Abramowitz from OU](https://outorah.org/p/6284/)
- [a more detailed video presentation from OU](https://www.ou.org/torah/mitzvot-series/six-constant-mitzvot/#?)

There are also full-book treatments of the topic including [Constant connection](https://www.artscroll.com/Products/COCOH.html) by R Yitzchak Coopersmith (based on the teachings of R Noach Weinberg from aish) and [The Six Constant Mitzvos](https://www.artscroll.com/Products/SIXH.html) (based on the teachings of R Yitzchok Berkowitz).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to "fully explain" any mitzvah (can mere mortals fully understand any Divine command?) but for a basic detailed explanation [see](https://www.sefaria.org/Biur_Halacha.1.1.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) the Biur Halacha in the beginning of the Mishna Berurah:

הוא כלל גדול בתורה וכו' - הרוצה לקיים שויתי כראוי יזדרז לקיים מה שנכתוב בשם ספר החינוך ומפני גודל חביבותם העתיקום כמה גדולים בספריהם וז"ל החינוך [בהקדמתו ובסימן כ"ה כ"ו תי"ז תי"ח תל"ב תפ"ז] שש מצות חיובן תמידי לא יפסקו מעל האדם אפילו רגע אחד כל ימיו וכל זמן וכל רגע שיחשוב בהן קיים מ"ע ואין קץ למתן שכר המצות ואלו הם.

א) להאמין שיש אלוה אחד בעולם שהמציא כל הנמצאות ומחפצו ורצונו הוא כל מה שהוא עכשיו ושהיה ושיהיה לעדי עד ושהוא הוציאנו ממצרים ונתן לנו התורה וזהו מ"ע דכתיב אנכי ה' אלהיך אשר הוצאתיך וגו' ופירושו תדעו ותאמינו שיש לעולם אלוה המשגיח שהרי הוצאתיך מארץ מצרים.

ב) שלא נאמין בשום אלהים זולתו שנאמר לא יהיה לך אלהים אחרים על פני ואפילו מודה שהקב"ה שולט על הכל רק שידמה בדעתו שמסר הנהגת העולם למלאך או לכוכב ה"ז מודה בע"ז ועובר על לא יהיה לך אלהים אחרים על פני אלא יאמין שהקב"ה בעצמו ובכבודו משגיח בכל העולמות ואין לשום נברא כח לעשות דבר בלתי רצונו ולכן נקרא הקב"ה אלהי האלהים.

ג) לייחדו שנא' שמע ישראל ה' אלהינו ה' אחד ופירושו שמע ישראל ודע כי ה' שהווה את הכל ברצונו והוא אלהינו המשגיח בכל העולמות הוא ה' אחד בלי שום שיתוף.

ד). לאהוב המקום ב"ה שנאמר ואהבת את ה' אלהיך וגו' וכיצד יגיע האדם לאהבה הוא ע"י התורה וכדאיתא בספרי לפי שנאמר ואהבת איני יודע כיצד לאהוב את המקום ת"ל והיו הדברים האלה אשר אנכי מצוך היום על לבבך שמתוך כך אתה מכיר את מי שאמר והיה העולם כלומר שע"י ההתבוננות בתורה יכיר את גדולתו של הקב"ה שאין לו ערך ולא קץ ותתיישב האהבה בלבו בהכרח. וענין המצוה שיראה האדם להשים כל מגמתו וכל מחשבתו אחר אהבת הש"י ויעריך בלבו כי כל מה שיש בעולם מעושר ובנים וכבוד הכל הוא כאין נגד אהבתו ית' וייגע תמיד בבקשת חכמת התורה למען ישיג ידיעה בה'. והקובע את מחשבתו בעניינים הגשמיים ובהבלי העולם שלא לש"ש רק להתענג ולהשיג כבוד ביטל עשה זו ועונשו גדול.

ה). להיות יראת הש"י על פניו תמיד לבלתי יחטא וע"ז נאמר את ה' אלהיך תירא ומי שבא דבר עבירה לידו חייב להעיר רוחו ולתת אל לבו באותו הפרק שהקב"ה משגיח בכל מעשי בני אדם אף אם יהיו במחשך מעשיהם וישיב להם נקם לפי רוע המעשה וכדכתיב אם יסתר איש במסתרים ואני לא אראנו נאום ה' וגו'.

ו). שלא נתור אחר מחשבת הלב וראיית העינים שנאמר ולא תתורו אחרי לבבכם וגו' ואמרו חכמים אחרי לבבכם זו אפיקורסות ואחרי עיניכם זו זנות ובכלל אפיקורסות הוא כל מחשבות זרות שהם היפך דעת התורה ובכלל זנות הוא מי שהוא רודף אחר תאות העולם מבלי שיכוין בהם כלל לכוונה טובה כלומר שלא יעשה אותם כדי שיעמוד בריא ויוכל להשתדל בעבודת בוראו רק כוונתו תמיד להרבות תענוגים גדולים לנפשו 
.כ"ז לקטתי מלשונו הנחמד בקצרה וקילורין הם לעינים ואשרי המקיימם כראוי ועיין בח"א כלל א' שהאריך ג"כ בהם

In brief summation they are:
1) The believe in G-d who created the whole world and that he took us out of Egypt and gave use the Torah

2) Not to believe in any ther god, or even that any other entity has any independent power.

3) That G-d is one with no partnership

4) To love G-d (to develop that love through Torah Study? It seems like the Beur Halacha is including this as part of the mitzva.) Love means to make ones entire focus on loving G-d, and realizing that no physical pleasure in the world is worth anything in comparison.

5) To constantly fear G-d in order not to sin.

6) Not to be drawn after intellectual concepts which are against the Torah, nor to pursue physical pleasures for their own sake.

(Sefaria doesn't have the English text, and I don't currently have the time to translate it all myself fully- I'll try later on if I have time.)

For anything more extensive than this, I suggest you check out the books quoted in the comments on the OP.